# Subscribing Salesforce to External Events

Tags: integration, platform-event

I have a scenario where Salesforce needs to be a subscriber for events published by an external system (non-salesforce). In this case do we need a Middleware like Mulesoft? Or is it possible for Salesforce to directly subscribe to external events without Middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really generic question as we do not really know about the external system, how data is published, it the data sequenced and data volume and size of each message, but there are several options. A middleware is preferred as it will provide failure management, retry mechanism, no governor limits, data mapping etc.

Other options:

1. Create a batch that periodically pulls data. This would be an pull mechanism, similar to reading a queue. Store the last Id fetched and continue from there.
2. Expose a service where the external system can push data. This may not be an option based on how external service creates data.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of *subscribe* as in the traditional publish-subscribe model will require a mid layer to broker these messages. This broker would be a message queue that sends messages to Salesforce (the subscriber) every time they are published by your external system.

If there is no middle layer what Salesforce would do is poll your external system. You could use [scheduled apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)  to periodically make an outbound call to your external system.